# выгрузить сайт Node.js на Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, hosting, virtual-hosts

[image: heroku logs] выдает ошибку h12 Request timeout. все делаю по инструкции с оффсайта. В чем может быть проблема? Возможно, что-то неправильно прописываю в коде проекта.

[проект на гитхаб](https://github.com/vitarunaeva/vlgplace.git)

Comment: выдает ошибку что с базой соединиться не может, а дальше уже таймаут.

Comment: а как правильно с базой в этом случае соединиться?module.exports = { 'url' : 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/vlg_place'};

Comment: в настройках хостера должна быть информация по идее